# Do prescribed glasses transmit light?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, lenses

If prescribed glasses can transmit light, what percentage of light can it transmit.

Comment: If my prescription glasses didn’t transmit light they would not be very useful.

Comment: Do they have an AR coating?

Answer (score 1):

Without light transmission, you will not be able to see anything since light is the way of transmitting the picture to your eye.